# Coolant loss out of overflow of an 1980 c-10

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system

I have an 1980s Chevy 305 engine. Was out for early morning breakfast and noticed coolant was coming out of overflow tank. The motor had not gotten warm yet. What could be causing it to overflow???

Comment: Try a new radiator cap. It's the least expensive part to replace which could cause this issue. If that doesn't work, you're looking at something a lot more major.